# Как принять xml сообщение в PHP?

Tags: php, xml

На указанный на сайте платежной системы url, на страницу которую я создал должны приходить xml сообщения об операциях. Как принять это сообщение, есть ли возможность создать какой нибудь слушатель xml сообщений? На if ($_GET) {..} if ($_POST) {..} никакой реакции, на стороне платежки говорят, что все отправляется.
Спасибо

Comment: Должно прийти сообщение формата 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
…
</order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения тела POST запроса используйте функцию `file_get_contents('php://input')`